# convert text hex to real hex representation C++

Tags: c++, hex

I have the following file format | 00 00 07 09 | for example in a text file
I need for a way to parse it so that each time I find a string between "|" convert the inside  to real hex representation

for instance  | 30 | will give me 0 how can it be done in C++ (damn C# makes you so lazy and dump).

this is the common format of the file

+++ath

|FF F4 FF FD 06|

/viewsource/template.html?

NAMENAME

|FF FF FF FF FF FF|

|13|

|05|

|00 00 00 08|

|00|

|0A|

|00 00|

c|82|Sc

=

GET

FTP|3A|/

|01 06 00 00 00|

HTTP/

PROPFIND

each line will be saved in a vector array 
that will be passed to the following function.

```
void WuManber::Initialize( const vector<const char *> &patterns, 
                  bool bCaseSensitive, bool bIncludeSpecialCharacters, bool       bIncludeExtendedAscii )
```

Comment: can any body give me hint, I will much appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use stringstream

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void foo()
{
    istringstream ss("30");
    int i;
    ss >> hex >> i;
}
```

Comment: this code only changes "any string 30 to hex" , what I need is any string between | | should be converted to its character equivalent, not only "30"

Comment: @WilliBurkhardt: you're not using the output part of `stringstream`.  Using `istringstream` provides a clearer intent.  Just thought it might help OP to have a code sample that actually compiles.  You can rollback the changes if you don't like them.

Comment: @sad: visit the post's history.  That change was performed by `izomorphius` before I edited you post to add the `using namespace` and change `stringstream` to `istringstream`.